# How do I check to see if multiple variables are equal to each other in batch files?

Tags: batch-file

I am creating a simple batch card game and i need to be able to check for flushes (five cards of the same suit). I need to be able to check if

```
%suit1% = %suit2% = %suit3% = %suit4% = %suit5%
```

and be able to execute a command if it is true. Yes I realize that in batch files i would use == instead of =

A big thank you to everyone for answering so quickly.  Does anyone have any suggestion for a code that would check for straights? (2,3,4,5,6) (10,J,Q,K,A)

Comment: Please accept an answer then ask a new question. In your new question you will need to post some code i.e. at the very least, what is the variable holding the face value?

Comment: Im really sorry. How do you accept an answer? Ill post a new thread with the code

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to emulate `AND` you need consecutive IFs:

```
 if %suit1% == %suit2% if %suit2% == %suit3% if %suit3% == %suit4% if %suit4% == %suit5% (
   echo do something
)
```

Answer (score 3):

```
if %suit1%%suit1%%suit1%%suit1% == %suit2%%suit3%%suit4%%suit5% (
   echo do something
)
```

should do what you want.

Comment: Let me recommend to put quotes around the two comparison expressions...

Answer (score 0):

For an arbitrary number of variables whose names begin with `suit`, you could do this:

```cmd
set "FLAG="
for /F "tokens=1,* delims==" %%V in ('set suit') do (
    if not "%suit1%"=="%%W" set "FLAG=#"
)
if not defined FLAG echo All variables `suit_` contain equal values.
```